# Promise.all concurrency

Tags: node.js, promise, electron, es6-promise, nedb

I'm developing an Electron app with NeDB storage (a javascript document oriented DB that uses Mongodb-like API), this code is not Electron-related though.

I'm trying to update `extractions` field of all documents. This code is simplified, the real code doesn't add just `[1, 2, 3]`.
The problem is this code add a second document with the same `_id` for each document in the db, so it's like bypasses the unique `_id` constraint.
You can run this code and see multiple `_id` with the same value.

**EDIT:** **to better see the problem**, please execute the PART 1 first, then comment it and execute the PART 2. You will see 2 documents with the same _id. One with  `extractions: [1, 2, 3]` and one with  `extractions: ["test1", "test2","test3"]` .

```
const Datastore = require('nedb');
let db = new Datastore({filename: "data2.db", autoload: true});


//---------PART 1------------
db.insert({_id: new Date('03/06/2017Z'), extractions: [1, 2, 3]}, function (err, newDoc) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log(newDoc);
});



//---------PART 2------------    
/* db.find({})
    .sort({_id: -1})
    .exec(function (err, docs) {
        var promiseList = [];
        docs.forEach(function (doc) {
            promiseList.push(PromisifiedFindAndUpdate(doc._id))
        });
        Promise.all(promiseList).then(values => {
            console.log(values)
        });
    });
  */

 let PromisifiedFindAndUpdate = function (id) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            db.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, doc) {
                let updated_extractions = ["test1", "test2","test3"];
                db.update({_id: id}, {$set: {"extractions": updated_extractions}}, {}, function (err, docs) {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    return resolve(docs);
                });
            });

        });
    };
```

Comment: `Promise.all` has no concurrency constraints - it just waits for promise results. You are starting all your operations inside that `forEach`, right after each other.

Comment: a concurrency issue was my hypothesis, do not overwrite documents, it duplicates the _id, having 2 same ids should be impossible.

Comment: _"You can run this code and see multiple _id with the same value"_. I don't see it. Run it once, see one `_id`. Run it again, get an error because there's already a document with that particular `_id` in the database.

Comment: ..and now please check in data2.db (the db is clear-text). You will see 2 documents with the same _id `1488758400000`.
The error you see comes from the `db.insert` row #5. You could comment that `db.insert()`, that's not the problem. The problem is the `findOne->update` chain doesn't work like you would expect if it's executed in a `Promise.all` pool.